# How to stop the file download in android by using DownloadManager?

Tags: android, gridview, download, android-download-manager

I　read the file from the SD card , and show on the Gridview.

When I select the item from `Gridview` and get the `position` of item.

I click the download button it will download the item.

How to Stop the item download when I using the `downloadManager` ?

The code is download button is like the following:

```
FileNode file = mFileList.get(temp_position) ;//Get the item I have select from Gridview

                                final String filename = file.mName.substring(file.mName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) ;
                                final String urlString = "http://" + mIp + file.mName ;

                                String serviceString = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE ;
                                DownloadManager downloadManager ;
                                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                        serviceString) ;

                                Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlString) ;
                                DownloadManager.Request request = new Request(uri) ;
                                request.setTitle(filename) ;
                                request.setDescription(urlString) ;

                                String ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
                                        .toLowerCase(Locale.US) ;
                                String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                                        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext) ;

                                Log.i("MIME", ext + "  ==>  " + mimeType) ;

                                if (mimeType != null) {
                                    request.setMimeType(mimeType) ;
                                }
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner() ;

                                request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED) ;

                                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(MainActivity.sAppName, filename) ;

                                downloadManager.enqueue(request) ;
```

How to Stop the item download when the file is downloading ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`DownloadManager#enqueue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#enqueue%28android.app.DownloadManager.Request%29) returns a `long` representing the `id` of the download taking place. Save that `long` in a variable.

Then, if you need to cancel the download, call [`DownloadManager#remove()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove%28long...%29) passing in that long.

Eg

```
//start a download
long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

//stop a download
downloadManager.remove(id);
```

Comment: Yes it is working but it needs wait a while for canceling (removing)

Answer (score 1):

first of all save the `long id` of download request in `shared preferences`

like this

```
SharedPreferences preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ACTIVITY CONTEXT);
    Editor PrefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
    PrefEdit.putLong("Download_ID", id);
    PrefEdit.commit();
```

now write a custom `broadcast receiver` which will listen to click on recently started download.

```
    public class DownloadManagerBR extends BroadcastReceiver {
        DownloadManager down_m ;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            down_m = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            SharedPreferences preferenceManager 
            = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            long id = preferenceManager.getLong("Download_ID", 0);
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

            }
            else if (DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action)) {
            //IN THIS SECTION YOU CAN WRITE YOUR LOGIC TO CANCEL DOWNLOAD AS STATED IN ABOVE ANSWER 
              downloadManager.remove(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

and register your broadcast receiver in `Android Manifest` like this

```
<receiver android:name=".DownloadManagerBR" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```